# Calculate the area of region with integral (infinite integral ?)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the area of a region not bounded and delimited by the curve of equation :

$$y=\frac{10}{x^2-10x+29}$$

And the line $x =3$

I need to calculate the area to the right...

My understanding is that I do an infinite integral (but I'm not sure at all) right ?

So I would do :

$$\int_3^\infty \frac{10}{x^2-10x+29} \mathrm{d}x$$

It seems so easy that I'm really not sure I'm doing the right thing (specially since I missed that theory... And I don't have the answer so I can't verify...)

Comment: There is some inconsistency about sign. I will assume the first is right, $x^2+10x+29$. This is $(x+5)^2+4$. Let $x+5=2t$. Now the integration is easy.  If it is $x^2-10x+29$, same method.

Comment: @AndréNicolas $(x-5)^2+4$

Comment: Sorry a typo... The second is actually right. Edited.

Comment: Just a note that it is called an improper integral rather than infinite integral.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: When I wrote the comment, OP had $x^2+10x+29$ in one place and $x^2-10x+29$ in another.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I know that Sir but I have a strong feeling that $x^2-10x+29$ is the correct one. I didn't mean to correct your comment.

Comment: It turns out you were right, OP edited the post. It all makes no difference, the procedure is precisely the same in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, that is exactly what you need to do. Just remember that: $$\int_{3}^{+ \infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2 - 10x + 19} = \lim_{c \to + \infty} \int_{3}^{c} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2 - 10x + 19}$$

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood something, yes, you are doing it right. For the next step, consider that:
$$ \int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{10\,dx}{x^2-10x+29}=\int_{-2}^{+\infty}\frac{10\,dx}{x^2+4}=\int_{-1}^{+\infty}\frac{5\,dx}{x^2+1}=5\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{15\pi}{4}.$$